# How to show more or less rows in a table by ng-click in angularjs with key, value pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got json where each parameter of the object has over 40 `key, val` pairs. All data is put into a `html` table on a page
I want user to be able to change a number of rows on a `html` page.

Firstly, to reduce number of rows into the table I wrote `ng-if` statement. I added `ng-if` because `LimitTo` doesn't work with `key, val` pairs. And actually I'm stucking here. The main problem in `key, val` pairs for me.
How can I add more/less buttons that helps user hide or show more rows when a `json` file contains `key,val` pairs.

My `html`

```
<table class="table ng-cloak" ng-if='$index<10'  ng-repeat="shop in shops | filter:isActive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Месяц</th>
      <th>Число кликов</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='(key, val) in shop.products' ng-if="$index < 10">
      <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ key }}</td>
      <td>{{ val }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my reduce `json`

```
[
  {
    "products": {
      "1359568800": 74,
      "1361988000": 71,
      "1364666400": 83,
      "1367258400": 72,
      "1369936800": 78
    },
    "name": "moskva",
    "avg_check": {
      "1359568800": 6479,
      "1361988000": 7375,
      "1364666400": 8477,
      "1367258400": 9292,
      "1369936800": 8357
    },
    "income": {
      "1359568800": 479515,
      "1361988000": 523662,
      "1364666400": 703601,
      "1367258400": 669072,
      "1369936800": 651921
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use default filter for objects. So use custom filter

```
app.filter('myLimitTo', [function(){
return function(obj, limit){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    if(keys.length < 1){
        return [];
    }

    var ret = new Object,
    count = 0;
    angular.forEach(keys, function(key, arrayIndex){
       if(count >= limit){
            return false;
        }
        ret[key] = obj[key];
        count++;
    });
    return ret;
};
```

Checkout the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/uLo0bo0u/