# MVC Angular - Remove hash from url

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes, angular-routing

I've a requirement where I need to `remove the #` from `url of angularJS` application because I need to `integrate` with `google drive api` and it is `not` accepting the `url's with #`.

So, I've gone thorugh some suggestions on web [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol) and have done some changes and `removed the hash`. but I'm `unable to load the page after refresh`.

previous url : http://localhost:54867/index.html#/Home/Chat
current url : http://localhost:54867/Home/Chat

as, there is `no index page` defined in the new url, we're unable to load the page after refresh.

Actually I've a `login page` and after login I'm `redirecting to the index` page using

`window.location.href = '../index.html';`

**My app.js Code**

```js
var plusapp = angular.module('plusapp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'checklist-model',
  'dx'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Account/Login', {
      templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    }).
    when('/Home/Chat', {
      templateUrl: '/Home/Chat',
      controller: 'ChatController'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/Home/Chat'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

and in my index page I've also place base tag this way

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
```

My final requirement is to `remove the hash` and `load the page even after refresh`.
BTW, I'm using `MVC` and `angularJS`

Can someone, please help me through this?
Do anyone got a link to a sample using mvc and angular to remove hash, where I can check and follow the steps?

Comment: Use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to remove the hash also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559271/how-to-show-more-or-less-rows-in-a-table-by-ng-click-in-angularjs-with-key-valu/37559841#37559841

Comment: I've already used the same code for removing hash. but may be I'm doing some other mistake. now, I need the page to load after refresh

Comment: as per the angulr Docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location 
Server side
Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

Comment: if you are using apache server, create a .htaccess file on the root of your shared Apache server. 
refer this link: https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Comment: @ebinmanuval : I've also tried pasting this code in my web.config. but after that, my application is not even logging in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27011093/2027813

Comment: checkout this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/30324160/3769965

Comment: @ebinmanuval : I've tried this. but when I've clicked the login button, the control is not hitting the controller function but I'm getting a success response in ajax callback with the whole page content as success data.
I've made a small video showing this. can you please check this out.
http://abc.uandmestaging.com:82/SampleFiles/LoginFail.swf

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$location.path('/');
```

instead of

```
window.location.href = '../index.html';
```

Comment: Have you passed $location to the controller.

or Try this way
 $scope.go = function ( path ) {
  $location.path( path );
};

<button ng-click="go('/home')"></button>

Comment: yeah.I've added $location as dependency like this 
`angular.module('Login', [])
    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {`

Comment: Have you tried this ,

$scope.go = function ( path ) { $location.path( path ); }; 

<button ng-click="go('/home')"></button>